# Can't push because I locally committed a file that is too large

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-enterprise

(Just in case it makes a difference, this is on Github Enterprise)

I can't push changes out to a repo because I unwittingly committed two overly-large files to my local repo. These two files exceed the size allowed by github. I'm now locally several commits behind the origin. I don't care about the large files and have since removed them, but `git push origin` still fails every time.

When I check the last commit in github, the repo is 10 days behind, meaning that not only do the large files fail, but the entire push fails. I apparently cannot push my repo anymore. Every time I try, I get this error:

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: File lib/abc.csv is 482.56 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 150.00 MB
remote: error: File lib/xyz.csv is 604.82 MB; this exceeds GitHub Enterprise's file size limit of 150.00 MB
To https://github.foobar.com/userx/myrepo
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.foobar.com/userx/myrepo'
```

- I want to push my current local repo out to the github repo.
- I don't care at all about the overly-large files. I **do not** need to push them out to github.
- My local repo is many commits ahead of the github repo. The commit with the overly-large files is not the most recent.

Is there a way to fix this without rolling my local repo all the way back to the commit where the large files were added?

Comment: what does git status tell you ?

Comment: also what does git remote -v tell you

Comment: `git status`: I'm 13 commits ahead of origin/master. `git remote -v`: lists the repo url twice: "origin <URL> (fetch)" and "origin <URL> (push)".

Comment: do git reflog  .. and see if the commit that has the large files is on top ..is it something like this position zero => 6560c15 HEAD@{0}

Comment: I found the commit and it is not on top: `f5d5fda HEAD@{18}`

Comment: do git reset --hard HEAD~1 and then try to do git push

Comment: Seeing same problem after `git reset --hard HEAD~1`. Push fails on large files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106049/discussion-between-nullsoulexception-and-matt-flowers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You must rebuild your history removing all commits which contain the big files.

To do so:

```
git rebase -i origin/master master
```

If your bad commits are only an add of big files, just delete them deleting the concerned lines in the rebase todo file.

If your big files belong to a more complex commit, use "edit" option in the rebase todo file on each concerned line. When the rebase operation stops just after the commit to amend:

```
git rm bigFile1 bigFile2
git commit --amend
git rebase --continue
```

Terminate the rebase, resolving all conflicts if necessary.

Finally, push again.

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can

`git reset --soft <commit>`

where "commit" was the commit where you committed the large file. (you can list your branches commits using git log) Then

`git rm --cached "largeFileName"`

then commit and push.

What I understand of it is that the soft reset changes you back to that previous commit without changing your local files. git rm --cached undoes you previous git add "largeFileName" so it isn't staged for commit

git status is a helpful command to see what git has prepared to commit (when my large file was finally off the stage it listed it as deleted in green)